# Is it true that if $bk\in Z(B\rtimes K)$ then $b\in Z(B)$?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Is this fact true?

Let be $G= B \rtimes K$ and I suppose that $w=bk \in Z(G)$, with $b\in B$ and $k \in K$.

Is it then true that $b\in Z(B)$?

I have tried to prove it but I didn't succeed. Thanks!

Comment: No it's not true in general. Let $B$ be a group with trivial centre, such as $S_3$ and take a semidirect product with $K=\langle t \rangle$ where $t$ induces an inner automorphism of $K$. Then $Z(G) \ne 1$ but $Z(B)=1$.